# When is binding transform feedback object not required?

Tags: webgl, transform-feedback

I have some sample code for a transform buffer object I've been trying to simplify down to the most minimal form and I've found that my code works the same if I omit `createTransformFeedback()` and `bindTransformFeedback()`. The only "transform feedback" code left is just `gl.bindBufferBase(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, buffer)`. I can only test this on two devices (Intel Iris and Qualcomm Adreno 610) but both run identically with or without binding any TFOs.

From all the documentation I've read, this doesn't make any sense to me. Is it actually required to call `bindTransformFeedback()` to get access to TFOs? Or is my code too "minimal".

The code below does not write to the canvas but only logs the buffer contents after two feedback passes. The relevant code is begins about half-way down. I've commented out code calling `createTransformFeedback()` and `bindTransformFeedback()`.

```
// Shaders
const transformVertexShader = `#version 300 es

layout(location=0) in vec2 shaderInput;

out vec2 shaderOutput;

void main() {
    shaderOutput = shaderInput * vec2(1.0, 10.0);
}`;
const transformFragmentShader = `#version 300 es

void main()
{
    discard;
}`;

// Create program
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');

const program = gl.createProgram();

const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, transformVertexShader);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);

const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, transformFragmentShader);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);

gl.transformFeedbackVaryings(program, ['shaderOutput'], gl.INTERLEAVED_ATTRIBS);

gl.linkProgram(program);

if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));

    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
    console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
}
gl.useProgram(program);

// Initialize VAOs, buffers and TFOs
const COUNT = 2000;
const A = 0;
const B = 1;

const sourceData = new Float32Array(COUNT).map((v,i) => i);

const buffer = [];
const vao = [];
// const tf = [];


for (const i of [A,B]) {
    vao[i] = gl.createVertexArray();
    buffer[i] = gl.createBuffer();
    // tf[i] = gl.createTransformFeedback();
    
    gl.bindVertexArray(vao[i]);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[i]);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, COUNT * 4, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
}

// Populate initial source data buffer
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[A]);
gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sourceData);

// Unbind everything (for no reason)
gl.bindVertexArray(null);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
gl.bindBufferBase(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, null);
// gl.bindTransformFeedback(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, null);

// First pass through the transform feedback A->B
gl.bindVertexArray(vao[A]);
// gl.bindTransformFeedback(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, tf[A]);
gl.bindBufferBase(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, buffer[B]);

gl.enable(gl.RASTERIZER_DISCARD);
gl.beginTransformFeedback(gl.TRIANGLES);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, COUNT / 2);
gl.endTransformFeedback();

// Second pass through the transform feedback B->A
gl.bindVertexArray(vao[B]);
// gl.bindTransformFeedback(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK, tf[B]);
gl.bindBufferBase(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, buffer[A]);

gl.beginTransformFeedback(gl.TRIANGLES);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, COUNT / 2);
gl.endTransformFeedback();

gl.flush();

// Check the final results
const fence = gl.fenceSync(gl.SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
const startTime = performance.now();
const check = () => {
    const status = gl.clientWaitSync(fence, 0 & gl.SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT, 0);
    if (status === gl.CONDITION_SATISFIED) {
        console.log(`sync after ${ performance.now() - startTime }ms`);
        const output = new Float32Array(COUNT);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[B]);
        gl.getBufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, output);
        console.log(`data finished fetching at ${ performance.now() - startTime }`);
        console.log(output);
        return;
    } else console.log('not finished, skipping');
    setTimeout(check);
};
check();
```

Answer (score 0):

I [completely missed](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transform_Feedback#:%7E:text=The%20feedback%20object%200%20is,you%20can%27t%20delete%20it.) that OpenGL provides a **default** transform feedback object that always exists, is bound until you unbind it (or bind to a different TFO) and cannot be deleted. If you are only pushing data back and forth between two buffers then you only need a single TFO, so it makes sense to use the default one.

I think the reason you would want to make two or more TFOs is if you were doing multiple draw calls in a single animation frame and wanted to retain info from both calls.

So for single transform-feedback programs, you only need to call `bindBufferBase(gl.TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER,...)`, `beginTransformFeedback(...)` and `endTransformFeedback()` since the default transform feedback object is already bound and ready for work.